# getting data from JSON in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i have this php file which get user's info from instagram API

```
<?php

//Get data from instagram api

$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];

if(!isset($_GET['count'])) $count = 20;

else $count = $_GET['count'];


//Query need client_id or access_token

$query = array(
    'client_id' => '8c81a425a76340a79aa66cb88aa74c89',
    'count'     => $count
);

$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='.$keyword.'&'.http_build_query($query);


try {
    $curl_connection = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //Data are stored in $data
    $data = curl_exec($curl_connection);
    curl_close($curl_connection);
    echo $data;

} catch(Exception $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

and return JSON string with 20 user's info like

```
  {"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"lama","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_42284_75sq_1353177507.jpg","full_name":"Li Shing","id":"42284"},{"username":"bekhand_lamasab","bio":"⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀  Kik : narsis.fashion \n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀ ⠀ ⚠️ sfs : 520 k ⚠️\nشات عضو فعال دوبار درهفته⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀ \nتوجهتبلیغات تک پیج انجام میشود⠀⠀⠀⠀","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-f.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xap1/10349797_785664258123877_321110299_a.jpg","full_name":"بزرگترین پیج ایرانی⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀","id":"1085311553"},{"username":"lamarquisette","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_279115230_75sq_1378119768.jpg","full_name":"Youssef Marquis","id":"279115230"},{"username":"timlaman","bio":"NatGeo Wildlife Photographer - Filmmaker - Field Biologist. Exploring wild places, rare species, rain forests and coral reefs.\nSee more on FB:","website":"https://www.facebook.com/TimLamanPhoto","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_195678468_75sq_1342554137.jpg","full_name":"Tim Laman","id":"195678468"},{"username":"lamamadelrap","bio":"#RIPMonkeyBlack\nMELYMEL NO UTILIZA FACEBOOK\n(Twitter) @MELYMELMELADA \n(RD) 809.360.9052\n(USA) 347.209.2816","website":"http://www.youtube.com/MelymelVEVO","profile_picture":"http://photos-g.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpf1/10693447_660276060736558_41448872_a.jpg","full_name":"MelyMel #zeroDembow","id":"305872466"},{"username":"lamarctaylor","bio":"no reality is the same.","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-f.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10731950_736068223151773_567726601_a.jpg","full_name":"lamarctaylor","id":"206461711"},{"username":"lamaisond","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-g.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10610996_331177297053686_1564957178_a.jpg","full_name":"","id":"1572747"},{"username":"joud_lama","bio":"لا أسمح بحفظ الصور والفديوات\nAll about my kids \nOur daily life in videos \nماشاء الله لاقوة الا بالله\nأستودع الله نفسي وعائلتي فاحفظنا من كل شر","website":"https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6PvF2TjuhQw","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_812908181_75sq_1399322579.jpg","full_name":"Joud_lama","id":"812908181"},{"username":"co._lams","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10731956_923164217707383_1481888166_a.jpg","full_name":"Lamar","id":"940742669"},{"username":"lamarca941fm","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1173210472_75sq_1394672048.jpg","full_name":"La Marca 94.1 FM","id":"1173210472"},{"username":"jonjonlamar","bio":"#Miami - #NYC. \nA Private Life is a Happy Life.. ✌️","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-e.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xap1/10483455_526566950776404_1475004702_a.jpg","full_name":"Jonathan Lamar Green","id":"18211272"},{"username":"lamafiabeats","bio":"✔Produccion y promocion de eventos\n✔cuenta aliada @shopvipcaracas\n✔publicidad y contacto +58 4242308332","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-b.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10731882_609733789138665_677150285_a.jpg","full_name":"la mafia lifestyle","id":"1533879744"},{"username":"marisa_lmp","bio":" Co-Founder : @micha_thailand\nผลิตภัณฑ์บำรุงผิวหน้า-ผิวกายขาวใส✨\nสั่งสินค้า : lmp.marisa/fon-lamapearl✨\nโทร: 092-2845899 , 085-389-5648 ","website":"http://www.lamapearl-skincare.com","profile_picture":"http://photos-f.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10731597_1494940657448173_726227876_a.jpg","full_name":"CEO of LaMaPearl Skincare","id":"10083328"},{"username":"lamaterialista1","bio":"Artista, Actriz, compositora Booking: RD 829-963-3653 USA 917-743-5599 / lamaterialistabooking@gmail.com / sigueme en twitter @LAMATERIALISTA1","website":"http://www.youtube.com/LaMaterialistaVEVO","profile_picture":"http://photos-c.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xap1/10665318_743709879028514_706220468_a.jpg","full_name":"LA REINA DE LA CHAPA QUEVIBRAN","id":"177807899"},{"username":"lamaris87","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-f.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10665398_1493770557570293_1634650289_a.jpg","full_name":"Lamaris","id":"30943990"},{"username":"lamaracuchis","bio":"Animadora de La Bomba \nFashion Blogger\nBlog: http://www.carlafieldproject.com\nChequea mi nuevo tutorial de maquillaje \naquí ⬇ espero lo disfruten.","website":"http://youtu.be/uLLv72vmgG4","profile_picture":"http://photos-a.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xfp1/891345_637029753056760_2048316896_a.jpg","full_name":"Carla Field","id":"238108076"},{"username":"lamaskeproduce","bio":"Producción de Tv y Radio,influyente,sarcástica,Yal, turista sin visa,Fan d Miley Cyrus,Dra. Polo y Dr. House.❌Cuenta Alterna @lamaskeproducetv","website":"http://www.lamaskeproduce.com","profile_picture":"http://photos-a.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xap1/925887_491093354357472_430852604_a.jpg","full_name":"Jenifel Galcia Cyrus","id":"30637470"},{"username":"dalailama","bio":"Welcome to the official Instagram Account of the Office of His Holiness the 14th Dalai Lama.","website":"http://www.dalailama.com/","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1044003089_75sq_1391167280.jpg","full_name":"Dalai Lama","id":"1044003089"},{"username":"lamarquenyc","bio":"Creative Consultancy co-founded by Meredith Melling and Valerie Boster; la marque, get set, go!","website":"http://lamarquenyc.com","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1031042100_75sq_1390883999.jpg","full_name":"la marque","id":"1031042100"},{"username":"lamasat.iq","bio":"➟ Official Account\n| صفحة ترفيهية منوعة |\n❤️لكل العراقيين والعرب❤️\nلا ندعي التميز ولكن نطمح لنكون الافضل \nadmins\nسوسومشمشمصطفئ","website":"","profile_picture":"http://photos-a.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10755896_316197498569544_758738327_a.jpg","full_name":"❣ لَمّـჰـاتْ عِرّاقـية ❣","id":"1360750684"}]}
```

and i have html file which send keyword to the php and return values

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.lamia.byethost18.com/get_info.php",
                data: {keyword: $("#keyword").val()},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: 
                    function(jsonStr) {
                        $.each(jsonStr.data, function(index, element){
                            $("#result").text(element.username);
                            $("#img").attr('src', element.profile_picture);
                        });
                    }
            });
        }); 
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <img src="" id="img" alt="" />
    <form name="contact" id="contact" method="get">
     keyword : <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="search!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

the problem is nothing is retrived ! i don't know if there is something wrong with my code ?

i just want to use `username` and `profile_picture` from retrived data and display it in the tags..

but nothing displayed i dont know why .. can someone help please ?

Comment: the first step in solving this is opening the console browser and checking for errors

Comment: Your response should already be in JSON format, no need to parse it again. Moreover try `console.log(jsonStr)` to see what was returned.

Comment: check `json_result` in console before loop

Comment: @Mahendra i got this: Object {meta: Object, data: Array[20]}  that's mean its retriveing data right ?

Comment: @NilotpalBarpujari  i got this: Object {meta: Object, data: Array[20]} that's mean its retriveing data right ?

Comment: Yes. so it seems everything was correct here, once check in other browsers

Comment: @Ghost  i got this: Object {meta: Object, data: Array[20]} that's mean its retriveing data right ?

Comment: @tatwany yes you are retrieving it right. i already checked your url in php and it works fine. try to check my answer below

Comment: @Mahendra what do you mean by check in other browsers ? already tried to run it on chrome and IE but the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the line with `JSON.parse()` as already explicitly set that you will receive a JSON:

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

Then in your success block, handle it as follows:

```
$.each(jsonStr.data, function(index, element){
    $("#result").text(element.username);
    $("#img").attr('src', element.profile_picture);
});
```

Comment: @tatwany yes it is working. i tried accessing your json and it works fine.

Comment: @tatwany i'l setup a demo so that you could see. i'l get back to you in a while

Comment: @tatwany its basically almost the same, of course i tweaked it a little bit but should be fairly straightforward http://codepad.viper-7.com/gMC8Ms

Comment: thank you so much for the demo! its almost the same as mine and working fine but its weird why mine is not working ?? i know i bothered you but can you please recheck my post i edited the html file maybe i missed something without knowing ?

Comment: besides this things: put `$keyword = urlencode($keyword);` and `$("#submit").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();`. there is nothing more that i can say really.

Comment: nothing different :( anyways really thank you sooo muchh for the help !! and i hope it will work soon :')

Comment: @tatwany oh okay, sorry it didn't help. anyways. this is a last ditch effort http://codepad.viper-7.com/sehCaQ

Comment: WORKED !! i just uploaded my file on another server and it worked !! thaaaank youu soo much !!!! but last question this will display only one user's info how to display all of the 20 users info ? should i return the for statement ?

Comment: @tatwany wow, i don't know what caused it maybe a configuration in the server, not really sure. but in that case you could just build the markup first, loop them all, then in the end, append them inside the container http://codepad.viper-7.com/BhaucB

Comment: yeah i dont know its really weird !! but really THANK YOU SOOO MUCH for the help really im so thankful for helping me out till the end !! worked perfectly just what i want again thanks alot !!!!! :)

Comment: @Sippy its the same code i just wanted him/her to check it for me